# Google cloud function http trigger issue with foreach loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an http trigger in cloud functions that appears to be working, however I am getting some logs that make me question the foreach loop.

Question: Is there a better way to write this function to not have to use a foreach loop?

Function:

```
const gamePin = req.body.gamepin
        const numPlayers = req.body.playercount.toString()

        var getGame = admin.firestore().collection('games')
        getGame = getGame.where('gid', '==', gamePin).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.empty) {

                console.log(`BODY: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);

                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    data.id = doc.id

                    console.log(`DOC DATA: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);

                    const currentNumPlayers = data.playercount
                    console.log(`currentNumPlayers: ${JSON.stringify(currentNumPlayers)}`);

                    const newPlayerCount = +numPlayers + +currentNumPlayers
                    console.log(`newPlayerCount: ${JSON.stringify(newPlayerCount)}`);

                    const newPlayerCountToString = newPlayerCount.toString()
                    console.log(`newPlayerCountToString: ${JSON.stringify(newPlayerCountToString)}`);

                    var updateGame = admin.firestore().collection('games').doc(data.id)
                    updateGame.update({
                        playercount: newPlayerCountToString
                    }).then(res => {
                        console.log(`COMPLETED UPDATE: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
                        res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Game: updated.', pin: gamePin })
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log(`ERROR IN QUERY: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                        res.status(500).send(err)
                    })

                })

            } else {
                console.log('could not find a match ', snapshot)
                res.send({ status: 400, message: 'Error. could not find a match' })
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).send(error)
        })
```

Here are the corresponding logs to go along with all those console.logs

[image]

UPDATED:

```
exports.addPlayerToGame = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, () => {


        // Check for POST request
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            res.status(400).send('Please send a POST request');
            return;
        }
        const gamePin = req.body.gamepin
        const numPlayers = req.body.playercount.toString()

        var getGame = admin.firestore().collection('games')
        getGame = getGame.where('gid', '==', gamePin).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.empty) {

                console.log(`BODY: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
                const doc = snapshot.docs[0];
                let data = doc.data()
                data.id = doc.id

                const currentNumPlayers = data.playercount
                console.log(`currentNumPlayers: ${JSON.stringify(currentNumPlayers)}`);

                const newPlayerCount = +numPlayers + +currentNumPlayers
                console.log(`newPlayerCount: ${JSON.stringify(newPlayerCount)}`);

                const newPlayerCountToString = newPlayerCount.toString()
                console.log(`newPlayerCountToString: ${JSON.stringify(newPlayerCountToString)}`);

                return admin.firestore().collection('games').doc(data.id)
                    .update({
                        playercount: newPlayerCountToString
                    })
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log(`COMPLETED UPDATE: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
                        res.send({
                            status: 200,
                            message: 'Game: updated.',
                            pin: gamePin
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(`ERROR IN QUERY: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                        // throw new Error(err);
                        res.status(500).send(err)
                    });

            } else {
                console.log('could not find a match ', snapshot)
                res.send({ status: 400, message: 'Error. could not find a match' })
            }

            console.log(`END:`);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(500).send(error)
        })

    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to execute in parallel several asynchronous tasks (the calls to the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) method, which returns a Promise), you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), as follows:

```
var getGame = admin.firestore().collection('games');
getGame = getGame
  .where('gid', '==', gamePin)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (!snapshot.empty) {
      console.log(`BODY: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);

      const promises = [];

      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let data = doc.data();
        data.id = doc.id;

        console.log(`DOC DATA: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);

        const currentNumPlayers = data.playercount;
        console.log(`currentNumPlayers: ${JSON.stringify(currentNumPlayers)}`);

        const newPlayerCount = +numPlayers + +currentNumPlayers;
        console.log(`newPlayerCount: ${JSON.stringify(newPlayerCount)}`);

        const newPlayerCountToString = newPlayerCount.toString();
        console.log(
          `newPlayerCountToString: ${JSON.stringify(newPlayerCountToString)}`
        );

        var updateGame = admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('games')
          .doc(data.id);

        promises.push(
          updateGame.update({
            playercount: newPlayerCountToString
          })
        );
      });

      return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(results => {
          console.log(`COMPLETED UPDATE: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
          res.send({
            status: 200,
            message: 'Game: updated.',
            pin: gamePin
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(`ERROR IN QUERY: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
          throw new Error(err);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('could not find a match ', snapshot);
      throw new Error('Error. could not find a match');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
```

---

**Update following your comment**: If you know for sure that there is only one document returned by the [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) ("there is only one document with that game pin") you can use the [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html#docs) property of the QuerySnapshot which returns "an array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot" and do as follows:

```
var getGame = admin.firestore().collection('games');
getGame = getGame
  .where('gid', '==', gamePin)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (!snapshot.empty) {
      console.log(`BODY: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);

      const doc = snapshot.docs[0];

      let data = doc.data();
      data.id = doc.id;

      const currentNumPlayers = data.playercount;
      const newPlayerCount = +numPlayers + +currentNumPlayers;
      const newPlayerCountToString = newPlayerCount.toString();


      return admin.firestore().collection('games').doc(data.id)
      .update({
            playercount: newPlayerCountToString
      })
      .then(() => {
          console.log(`COMPLETED UPDATE: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
          res.send({
            status: 200,
            message: 'Game: updated.',
            pin: gamePin
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(`ERROR IN QUERY: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
          throw new Error(err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('could not find a match ', snapshot);
      throw new Error('Error. could not find a match');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
```

---

**Second update**, see comments in the code:

```
exports.addPlayerToGame = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    // Check for POST request
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
      res.status(400).send('Please send a POST request');
    }

    const gamePin = req.body.gamepin;
    const numPlayers = req.body.playercount.toString();

    admin   //Here I would not use a getGame variable
      .firestore()
      .collection('games')
      .where('gid', '==', gamePin)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
          console.log(`BODY: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);

          const doc = snapshot.docs[0];
          let data = doc.data();
          data.id = doc.id;

          const currentNumPlayers = data.playercount;
          console.log(
            `currentNumPlayers: ${JSON.stringify(currentNumPlayers)}`
          );

          const newPlayerCount = +numPlayers + +currentNumPlayers;
          console.log(`newPlayerCount: ${JSON.stringify(newPlayerCount)}`);

          const newPlayerCountToString = newPlayerCount.toString();
          console.log(
            `newPlayerCountToString: ${JSON.stringify(newPlayerCountToString)}`
          );

          return admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('games')
            .doc(data.id)
            .update({
              playercount: newPlayerCountToString
            })
            .then(() => { //Here, I don't understand why do you return res. The update method returns an empty Promise so just do .then(() => {}}
              console.log(`COMPLETED UPDATE`);  //Here don't use res, as it is the Response object and represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request
              res.send({
                status: 200,
                message: 'Game: updated.',
                pin: gamePin
              });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(`ERROR IN QUERY: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
              // throw new Error(err);
              res.status(500).send(err); //I am not sure what is better... throwing an Error or sending back a 500 response code.
            });
        } else {
          console.log('could not find a match ', snapshot);
          res.send({ status: 400, message: 'Error. could not find a match' });
        }

        console.log(`END:`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. One more question: there is only one docuement with that game pin. Do I have to use the `snapshot.forEach` approach?

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I got an error: `TypeError: getGame.doc is not a function
    at getGame.where.get.then.snapshot (/user_code/index.js:138:32)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
`

Comment: That went through however i got both of these console.logs `COMPLETED UPDATE: {"_writeTime":{"_seconds":1556892738,"_nanoseconds":570533000}}`, `ERROR IN QUERY: {}`

Comment: Interestingly enough I ran it a couple more times and it does what it is supposed to do but I only get this error `ERROR IN QUERY: {}`

Comment: You may have a problem with the  `res` variable. It seems it is at the same time holding a value and being the response variable for the HTTPS Cloud Function.... Can you update the question with the **entire** code of the Cloud Function.

Comment: Sure one second

Comment: Did I not use the variable properly here? `admin   //Here I would use a getGame variable that` `var getGame = admin.firestore().collection('games')
        getGame = getGame.where('gid', '==', gamePin).get()`

Comment: It seems that the foreach loop approach was working better. Maybe I should just stick with that :)

Comment: No need to use a getGame variable, you can chain the method calls. It should work with the one document version....

Comment: ok, maybe I am not understanding this comment: `admin   //Here I would use a getGame variable that` are you saying to use the variable?

Comment: Oh, my fault!! Sorry. I meant  "//Here I would NOT use a getGame variable"

Comment: :) oh ok, let me run it again

Comment: That WORKED! Thank you so much for all your help. I have one more function. Can I post it in a new question and get you to take a look at it as well. similar situation with the promise

Comment: Sure! Happy that I could help!

Comment: ok, here is the second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972558/having-a-promise-issue-with-my-google-cloud-function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192791/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-jason).

Comment: hi @Renaud I was wondering if you had a second to look at the progress on the other function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972558/having-a-promise-issue-with-my-google-cloud-function Its almost complete. its just missing one of the foreach loops in the promise. I understand if you can't but thought I would ask :)