# Having a promise issue with my google cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an http trigger in cloud functions that is working, however I am getting some logs come back in a weird order. I am pretty sure I have not executed the promises correctly.

here is the code:

```
exports.createGame = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, () => {

        // Check for POST request
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            res.status(400).send('Please send a POST request');
            return;
        }
        const createGame = admin.firestore().collection('games')

        generatePin() 

        function generatePin() {
            ...pin generating code goes here...

            addGame(newGidToString)
        }

        function addGame(newGidToString) {
            var getGame = admin.firestore().collection('games')
            getGame = getGame.where('gid', '==', newGidToString)
            getGame.get().then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {

                    console.log('BODY ', req.body)

                    const promises = [];

                    const gameTitle = req.body.gametitle
                    const targetGID = req.body.target
                    const numPlayers = req.body.playercount.toString()

                    const newGID = newGidToString
                    const collections = ['games', 'clues', 'detours', 'messages', 'questions', 'tagstate']
                    collections.forEach(function (element) {
                        console.log('start loop', element)
                        let elementsRef = admin.firestore().collection(element)
                        elementsRef = elementsRef.where('gid', '==', targetGID)
                        elementsRef.get().then(snapshot => {
                            var batch = admin.firestore().batch()
                            snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                                // change the gid to the new game gid
                                let data = doc.data()
                                data.gid = newGID

                                if(data.template){
                                    data.template = false
                                }

                                if(!data.parent) {
                                    data.parent = targetGID
                                }

                                if (!data.playercount) {
                                    data.playercount = numPlayers
                                }

                                if (data.gametitle) {
                                    data.gametitle = gameTitle
                                }

                                let elementRef = admin.firestore().collection(element).doc()
                                batch.set(elementRef, data)
                            })
                            batch.commit().then(data => {
                                console.log('complete batch ', element)
                            })
                        })
                    })
                    res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Game: added.', pin: newGID})
                    console.log('completed');
                } else {
                    console.log('found a match ', snapshot)
                    // re-run the generator for a new pin
                    generatePin()
                }
            })
        }
    })

})
```

Here is a screen shot of the console logs.

[image]

Notice the order of the logs. It would seem logical that `completed` would come at the end fo the loops.

Any help is great appreciated.

UPDATE:

```
function addGame(newGidToString) {
            var getGame = admin.firestore().collection('games')
            getGame = getGame.where('gid', '==', newGidToString)
            getGame.get().then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {

                    console.log('BODY ', req.body)

                    const promises = [];

                    const gameTitle = req.body.gametitle
                    const targetGID = req.body.target
                    const numPlayers = req.body.playercount.toString()

                    const newGID = newGidToString

                    const collections = ['games', 'clues', 'detours', 'messages', 'questions', 'tagstate']
                    collections.forEach(function (element) {

                        console.log('start loop', element)

                        let elementsRef = admin.firestore().collection(element)
                        elementsRef = elementsRef.where('gid', '==', targetGID)
                        // elementsRef.get().then(snapshot => {

                        const promGet = elementsRef.get();  //lets get our promise
                        promises.push(promGet);             //place into an array
                            promGet.then(snapshot => {  //we can now continue as before

                            var batch = admin.firestore().batch()

                            snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                                // change the gid to the new game gid
                                let data = doc.data()
                                data.gid = newGID

                                if(data.template){
                                    data.template = false
                                }

                                if(!data.parent) {
                                    data.parent = targetGID
                                }

                                if (!data.playercount) {
                                    data.playercount = numPlayers
                                }

                                if (data.gametitle) {
                                    data.gametitle = gameTitle
                                }

                                let elementRef = admin.firestore().collection(element).doc()
                                batch.set(elementRef, data)
                            })
                            batch.commit().then(data => {
                                console.log('complete batch ', element)
                            })

                        })
                    })
                    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                        res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Game: added.', pin: newGID })
                        console.log('completed');
                    });
                    // res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Game: added.', pin: newGID})
                    // console.log('completed');
                } else {
                    console.log('found a match ', snapshot)
                    // re-run the generator for a new pin
                    generatePin()
                }
            })
        }
```

SECOND UPDATE: (based off Keith's answer)

```
function addGame(newGidToString) {
            var getGame = admin.firestore().collection('games')
            getGame = getGame.where('gid', '==', newGidToString)
            getGame.get().then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {

                    console.log('BODY ', req.body)

                    const gameTitle = req.body.gametitle
                    const targetGID = req.body.target
                    const numPlayers = req.body.playercount.toString()

                    const newGID = newGidToString

                    const promises = [];

                    const collections = ['games', 'clues', 'detours', 'messages', 'questions', 'tagstate']
                    collections.forEach(function (element) {

                        console.log('start loop', element)

                        let elementsRef = admin.firestore().collection(element)
                        elementsRef = elementsRef.where('gid', '==', targetGID)

                        const getPromise = elementsRef.get();  //lets get our promise
                        promises.push(getPromise);             //place into an array
                        getPromise.then(snapshot => {  //we can now continue as before

                            var batch = admin.firestore().batch()

                            snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                                // change the gid to the new game gid
                                let data = doc.data()
                                data.gid = newGID

                                if(data.template){
                                    data.template = false
                                }

                                if(!data.parent) {
                                    data.parent = targetGID
                                }

                                if (!data.playercount) {
                                    data.playercount = numPlayers
                                }

                                if (data.gametitle) {
                                    data.gametitle = gameTitle
                                }

                                let elementRef = admin.firestore().collection(element).doc()
                                batch.set(elementRef, data)
                            })
                            batch.commit()
                        })
                    })
                    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                        res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Game: added.', pin: newGID })
                        console.log('completed from promise');
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('found a match ', snapshot)
                    // re-run the generator for a new pin
                    generatePin()
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: `forEach` won't wait until all your `async` stuff is done

Comment: `const promises = [];`  It looks like you was nearly on the right track here.  Inside you `forEach`, push the promises onto this, then `Promise.all(promises).then(`

Comment: @Keith thank you for responding, I have two foreach loops which one am I supposed to do that with?

Comment: @Keith Do I push from within this loop `snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {` or this one `collections.forEach(function (element) {` ?

Comment: It all depends on what's `sync` and what's `async`, so looking at your code `elementsRef.get()` is `async`, as such just push this onto your promise array.

Comment: @Keith something like this? `promises.push(elementsRef)`

Comment: @Keith also, did you notice `batch.commit()` this has a promise attached as well.

Comment: No it's the `get`, that's the promise..   To make things simply you can do -> `promGet = elementsRef.get(); promises.push(promGet); promGet.then(....` etc, you can do this for you `commit` too.

Comment: @Keith if you can put this into the code as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping with promises, one thing to remember is if you do a `forEach`, it's not going to wait.

It appears that what the OP wants to do is before he hits the complete, and does a res send, wants to make sure all promises have been completed.

`Promise.all`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all  , is exactly what this does.

So every time you create a promise if you push this onto an array, we can later use `Promise.all` to make sure all the promises are complete.

So if we replace

```
elementsRef.get().then(snapshot => {
```

with

```
const promGet = elementsRef.get();  //lets get our promise
promises.push(promGet);             //place into an array
promGet.then(snapshot => {          //we can now continue as before
```

Your promise is now stored for later so that `Promise.all` can check to make sure everything has complete.  You could do this in one line, but I feel it's easier to see what's happening this way. eg->

```
promises.push(promGet.then(snapshot => {
```

Finally now we have got our promise array, before we do our `res.send`, lets make sure they have all completed.

```
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Game: added.', pin: newGID})
  console.log('completed');
});
```

One thing to keep in mind when using Promises this way, is that you have a fair few things going on at the same time, sometimes this can be an issue, eg.  connected to some service might put restrictions on the number of concurrent connections etc.    So in these cases it might be an idea doing things in series or a mix of both.  There are even libs that can do concurrecy, eg.  Do only  X amounts of promises at a time.

And finally, if you can use `async / await`, I'd advice using them, as it makes Promises so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I did this. `let elementsRef = admin.firestore().collection(element)
                        elementsRef = elementsRef.where('gid', '==', targetGID)
                        // elementsRef.get().then(snapshot => {

                        const promGet = elementsRef.get();  //lets get our promise
                        promises.push(promGet);             //place into an array
                            promGet.then(snapshot => {  //we can now continue as before`

Comment: and then this `Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                        res.send({ status: 200, message: 'Game: added.', pin: newGID })
                        console.log('completed');
                    });`

Comment: but it did not work. not sure if I did this correct

Comment: if it is easier to see, I can update my question with the revised code based off your answer

Comment: @Jason  It looks like you did it correct, but yes, maybe update your answer.  Also if this is Javascript client site, make sure it's not running the cached version.

Comment: Thank you Keith, After some rearranging I was able to get it to work as shown in my second update.

Comment: Oh, nice one,.. Was just looking at update when this popped up.. :)

Comment: Just to be safe. I did that the correct way right? see second update. I took out the .then on the batch commit

Comment: It shouldn't of really made any difference,  it would have just been waiting for more things to finish..  Taking out the batch.commit part would just mean it could get to your complete before the commits had been completed.  This might not be an issue.  One thing I have noticed is that you appear not to have any error handling, so any errors might go silent.   If you do `Promise.all(...).catch(e => ...).then(() => ...`

Comment: ok two things: I do want to wait for the `batch.commit` to finish before returning the promise. How can I do that? second in your response you have `.catch` before `.then` is that intentional?

Comment: I'm so used to `async / await` nowadays.. :),  yes, better do -> `then` `catch`, as I think `catch` `then` is more like a `finally`, and in this case you wouldn't want that.   When you had the commit in your `promise.all`, in what way did it not work?

Comment: I would see the batch.commit console.log show up after the promise complete log